# How to get response from unirest nodejs POST call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

I have used the following code sample to call a API which returns a access token.

```js
var responsedata = '';

unirest.post('http://sandbox.com/api/getToken')
  .headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  .send('apiKey=xewsdw232')
  .send('username=theuser')
  .end(function (response) {

    console.log(response.body);
    responsedata = response.body;
    
    
  });

console.log(responsedata);
```

> Response

`{ data: { token: 'JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9',transID:'00582',errorCode: '00',errorMessage: '' } }`

I do get response which gets logged into the console but unable to assign it to a variable to that I can work with it outside the call function. I am struggling with understanding how callbacks work in javascript.

Comment: Please show us the response you get.

Comment: Question edit included the response log

Comment: you should understand how Javascript work first. JS working asynchronous. you are trying to get value before its assigned.

Comment: I think in your code you would use `responsedata.data`. Can you post the code where you are trying to use the data, with an explanation of what isn't working?

Comment: The last line console.log(responsedata) logs empty string. So I guess the variable responsedata isn't getting response.body value

Comment: @AhmedReza check this example. you are making request. it takes time but your program will not stop. so you can get value outside of function 
https://repl.it/repls/OutgoingFreshOutput

Comment: @NazirDogan excellent example to explain asynchronous behaviour of js. Makes sense now. Now need to find a way to wait until the API call is complete and then exit the function

Comment: @AhmedReza your welcome.you should put the other function inside success callback.

Comment: I post as answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP requests are asynchronous in nature. You do not get the response instantly which means javascript doesn't wait for the response instead execution is continued and whenever a response is returned, the callback gets called.

If you want to return this response, encapsulate this code in the function and return a resolved promise.

```
function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    unirest.post('http://sandbox.com/api/getToken')
      .headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
      .send('apiKey=xewsdw232')
      .send('username=theuser')
      .end(function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
          return reject(response.error)
        }
        return resolve(response.body);
      });
  })
}
getToken().then((body) => console.log("success", body)).catch((error) => 
console.log("error", error))
```

Answer (score 2):

JS working asynchronous. you are trying to get value before its assigned.check this example. you are making request. it takes time but your program will not stop. so you cannot get value outside of function https://repl.it/repls/OutgoingFreshOutput